# Problem filtering information in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, aggregate, group-concatenation

I've a little problem with a SQL query.

The objective is to get an employee profile related to a role.

Table EMPLOYEE (Louis,Mary,Christian):

- EmpId
- EmpName

Table ROLE (Chef,Waiter,NULL):

- RoleID
- RoleNAME

Table EMPROLE:

- EmpId
- RoleId

An employee should have 0..n roles. To get an employee profile:

- IF Chief -> BOS
- ElseIF waiter -> CHA
- Else -> CUS

The objective is to print EmpName, all roles, and the profile.

I can print all roles with `group_concat` and get the role using `case` but that only works if the role is the first occurrence in the `group_concat` column.

My query:

```
select EMPLOYEE.EmpName,GROUP_CONCAT(ROLE.RoleName) as role_, 
(CASE WHEN ROLE.RoleName = "Chief" THEN "BOS" 
CASE WHEN ROLE.RoleName = "waiter" THEN "CHA" 
ELSE THEN "NULL" 
END) AS PROFILE 
FROM EMPLOYEE,ROLE,EMPROLE 
WHERE EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEEID=EMPROLE.EMPLOYEEID AND EMPROLE.ROLEID=ROLE.ROLEID group by EMPLOYEE.EmpName;
```

Output:

```
+----------+--------------------------------+--------+
| EmpName  | roles                          | PERFIL |
+----------+--------------------------------+--------+
| Louis    | Waiter,Chief                   | NULL   |
| Mary     | Chief,Waiter                   | BOS    |
| Christian| NULL                           | NULL   |
+----------+--------------------------------+--------+
```

How can I get the information right?

Comment: What did you want for `PROFILE`?  Perhaps:  BOS, BOS, NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be closer:

```
select  e.EmpName,
        GROUP_CONCAT(r.RoleName) AS roles
        CASE
            WHEN FIND_IN_SET("Chief",   GROUP_CONCAT(r.RoleName)) THEN "BOS"
            WHEN FIND_IN_SET("waiter ", GROUP_CONCAT(r.RoleName)) THEN "CHA"
            ELSE                                                       "CUS"
        END  AS Profile
    FROM  EMPLOYEE AS e
    JOIN  EMPROLE  AS er  ON e.EMPLOYEEID = er.EMPLOYEEID
    JOIN  ROLE     AS r   ON er.ROLEID = r.ROLEID
    group by  e.EMPLOYEEID;
```

Notes:

- Please use the `JOIN ON` syntax instead of commajoin and `WHERE`.
- The `GROUP_CONCAT` occurs 3 times; that can be avoided with the expense of a nested query.  I did not think it was worth it.
- Be sure to have something like this on `EMPROLE`:

  ```
  PRIMARY KEY(employeeid, roleid),
  INDEX(roleid, employeeid)
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much Rick, it works!